# Collapsible Tables in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

So i'm using Bootstrap 4 and Meteor and trying to create a table that collapses when you click on a row element. I'm having a problem with the collapsing row resizing down to the size of the first `<td>` element even if i'm using `colspan="3"`. Here's the HTML:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Tech</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {{#each school}}
  <tbody>
    <tr class="school-row">
      <td scope="row">{{trimString name}}</td>
      <td>{{trimString tech}}</td>
      <td>{{formatDate createdAt}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="room-collapse">
      <td scope="row" colspan="3" data-parent=".room-collapse">
        <p>Hello this is a test.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

I'm using `.room-collapse` as the jQuery target. I'm not applying any extra styling at the moment and the jQuery triggers are working fine. Any ideas or is this just a bug?

Comment: A lot of times w/ JS-driven UI changes in Meteor/Blaze you run into a timing issue where the JS executes on page load, but the elements aren't there yet. For example, you have some JS that makes a bunch of cells invisible when the document onReady is fired. In Meteor/Blaze the onReady would occur when the page builds, but the table cells would not be there yet since the page is build reactively and hasn't finished yet. Maybe this is the case? The only solution would be to either to a) use server-side rendering for the page, or b) place the code in question in the onRendered of your template.

Comment: In the example above, the `.room-collapse` is firing when `.school-row` is clicked.  I also have an `#if Template.subscriptionsReady` statement wrapped around the whole template.  You may be right but it seems like a bug dealing with Bootstrap's Tables and Collapse to me.  The collapsing table resized when I put the target on the `<table>` element but when I wrapped the table with a `<div>` and put the target in the div it performed as expected.

Comment: The question is: Is the mechanism that drives the update to DOM driven by JS or not, and if it is, is it reliant on the DOM being ready when the JS runs, or is it doing an event delegation. There is really nothing I know of built into CSS to handle showing/hiding something based on a click even that doesn't required JS in there somewhere. I have seen time and time again where Meteor breaks stuff like this because of how DOM is built and when the onReady event is triggered. If you think it's a bug in BS4, see if you can recreate with plain JS and HTML and take Meteor out of the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was simply that the Collapse target element needed to be a `<div>` in my case.  Any table element I tried to attach to the collapse failed but after I nested the `<div>` I was good to go.  Code below as example:

```
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
          <th>School</th>
          <th>Tech</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {{#each school}}
      <tbody>
        <tr class="school-row">
          <td scope="row">{{trimString name}}</td>
          <td>{{trimString tech}}</td>
          <td>{{formatDate createdAt}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td scope="row" colspan="3">
            <div class="room-collapse">
              <p>Hello this is a test.</p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      {{/each}}
    </table>
```

Hopefully this helps somebody.  It seems to be something with Bootstrap 4 or the particular package that i'm using (which is `twbs:bootstrap@=4.0.0-alpha2`).

Short answer: wrap the collapse in a `<div class="target">` with "target" being your target `.class` or `#id`.